# Why ++a increment twice?

Tags: javascript

A friend was asked this question at a Javascript job interview today:

Why does ++a increment twice ?

```js
a = b = 9**17-2
++a
console.log(a-b) //Why is it 2 ?
```

Comment: I'm getting `0` as a result of this code

Comment: floating point precision is fun

Comment: its not safe integer, check Number.isSafeInteger(9**17-2) its false

Comment: though i know what causes this, i think it's a bad interview question. i don't like indirect questions. solving them is always like playing a lottery. sometimes you get it right away, sometimes you just have a bad day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the value is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and cannot be represented exactly with IEEE754 double precision numbers (that JS uses as its number representation format)

`16677181699666566` is `1101100111111110011101111001100010000001100101000011` in IEEE754 double precision

and `16677181699666568` is `1101100111111110011101111001100010000001100101000100`

You see that binary still differs by one, but it's not enough precision to display it properly in human readable format.